# Plotting discrete point magnitudes in Octave

Tags: plot, octave

Ok, here's the thing:

I have a map (X and Y coordinates). On Top of that, I can put some Z magnitudes (currently dealing with vibration magnitudes). I can surf or contour this:
[my map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06L1W.png)

So, what I want to do, is to specify small circles with a delimited area and in these I want to fill them with a color that will depend on their magnitude.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Update!

After playing for a while with scatter3 I was able to generate this: [scatter plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BXlX.png)

It was actually not a big deal, does anybody know how to hide the 0 point values?

Comment: surf, contour and mesh.  I am honestly not the advanced user in octave. I am thinking of assigning the colors myself in autocad (for example) but I think Octave can handle this task, right? I have looked on the web, and still have not found any good example.....

Comment: you can 'cheat' to hide zero values by setting them to `nan`, e.g. `Z(Z==0) = nan`